# If statement not working when it really should

Tags: html, if-statement

Okay, this is by far one of the strangest things I've come across in some time.. I have the following piece of code in one of my woocommerce files:

```
<?php $titlevar = wp_title('', 0); ?>
                <?php echo $titlevar; ?>


                <?php if($titlevar == "Men") { ?>

                <div id="sidemenu" style="float:left;width: 180px;float:left;height:100px">


                <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'sidemenumen' )); ?>

                </div>

                <?php } ?>
```

As you can see, if my $titlevar variable equals "Men", it should display a div with  a menu inside. I've echo'ed the variable at the top and it actually outputs 'Men' (without quotes of course), how is it possible that it's not showing my div??

Comment: Is it really outputting "Men"? Or is it covered inside some HTML tags, blank characters, separators or encoding (as it's from a WordPress function, that may do so)? Could you take a look at the source code of your output page?

Comment: That's really what it's ouputing, no tags around it whatsoever, I checked the source code..

Comment: try strcmp and see if you get the same behavior.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php